# parse text file with regexp or not

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a text file with the following content:

```
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:45 www.site.com    0   None    BusyCount: 00:00:00.0000880
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:45 www.site.com    0   None    GetBusyPlace: 00:00:00.7759916
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:44 www.site.com    0   None    GetHallPlan: 00:00:00.0098537
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:44 www.site.com    0   None    GetSeatPrice: 00:00:00.1462649
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:40 www.site.com    0   None    BusyCount: 00:00:00.0000988
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:40 www.site.com    0   None    GetBusyPlace: 00:00:00.7330764
Warning 18.05.2012 16:27:39 www.site.com    0   None    GetHallPlan: 00:00:00.0435432
```

I have three array:

```
List<string> getSeatPrice = new List<string>();
List<string> getBusyCounts = new List<string>();
List<string> getHallPlan = new List<string>();
```

How can I parse this text file and get time from string, for example `GetBusyPlace: 00:00:00.7759916` and put in appropriate array?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? What's the columns separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like each line in your file is whitespace-separated set of tokens. The easiest thing to do in this case would be to use `String.Split()`, and get the token that you want by its position in the string.

```
var getSeatPrice = new List<string>();
var getBusyCounts = new List<string>();
var getHallPlan = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("c:\\data\\myfile.txt")) {
    var tokens = line.Split('\t', ' ');
    var kind = tokens[6];
    var value = tokens[7];
    switch (kind) {
        case "GetSeatPrice:":
            getSeatPrice.Add(value);
        break;
        case "BusyCount:":
            getBusyCounts.Add(value);
        break;
        case "getHallPlan:":
            getHallPlan.Add(value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a fixed width field format.

I suggest using the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class that lives in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace (just add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and you are good to go).

It is a .NET library that you can setup to specify the field widths and types in order to get a strongly typed view of the fields.